# Cutting out shape to reveal what's behind

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following MWE displays the desired output, but the question is whether (and how) the same result can be achieved by somehow redefining lines (1) and (2) to "cut out" the inner square, so that line (3) is redundant. I appreciate that this picture is simple, but one can easily imagine more complicated cases.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,-1)--++(4,4);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0)--++(2,0)--++(0,2)--++(-2,0)--++(0,-2); % (1)
\draw (0.5,0.5)--++(1,0)--++(0,1)--++(-1,0)--++(0,-1); % (2)
\draw (0.5,0.5)--++(1,1); % (3)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can clip with the `even odd rule` (or the other one …).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel What's `evenoddrule `? I didn't see it in the pgfmanual.

Comment: @Geoff: notice that the key is `even odd rule` with _spaces_; you can find it in 15.4.2 Graphic Parameters: Interior Rules at the end of the page.

Comment: Ah! Those spaces help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Filling

If you actually want to fill the outer rectangle but not the inner, you can use the `even odd rule` (PGF manual, pp. 163f.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule]
\draw (-1,-1) -- ++ (4,4);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) rectangle ++ (2,2) (.5,.5) rectangle ++ (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Clipping

Another approach would be clipping, but as you want to “reverse-clip” the line to the boxes you will need a tweaked version of clip.

In this small example the following code suffices, but if you want to draw more or more sophisticated pictures you will need the `reverseclip` style from the referenced answer and/or a `scope`.

#### Reference

- Jake’s answer to [How can I invert a 'clip' selection within TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12010/16595)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[even odd rule]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (1.5,1.5) rectangle (.5,.5);
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\clip (0,0) rectangle (2,2) (1.5,1.5) rectangle (.5,.5) (3.1,3.1) rectangle (-1.1,-1.1);
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\draw (-1,-1)--++(4,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The "Filling" solution is what I was looking for. It keeps the code more logical (IMHO), in that we create the back line first, then the box with hole on top of that. Many thanks.